Asus Vivobook extremely slow after suspend
After waking up from suspend, Asus laptop is extremely slow. Waking up lasts around two minutes (after pressing the power button). Than it is super slow. Web browser or System Monitor won't start and only basic terminal commands can be executed and after executing some command with sudo it just freezes the terminal. Wifi is also not working after waking up.
After restarting (which has to be done by holding power button for few seconds, because otherwise it takes about half an hour to restart) everything works fine till another suspend. I am dualbooting Windows 11, but secure boot is turned off as it is recommended usually.
Some people with Asus laptop experienced same problem and I've tried all fixes mentioned in these questions, but none of them worked for me:

Ubuntu 22.04 : Laptop don't wake up after suspend
Ubuntu 22.04 won't wake up from sleep
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2302105#p2302105
https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=155699

I've also tried switching kernel to both older (5.13.5) and newer (6.8.8) version or switching nvidia driver to the one that is marked as (open kernel), but it didn't help too.
System info (GPU is NVIDIA RTX 4050 and Ubuntu 24.04):
CPU: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700H (-MST AMCP-)
speed/min/max: 440/400/4600:4700:3500 MHz Kernel: 6.8.0-39-generic x86_64
Up: 3m Mem: 2.61/30.97 GiB (8.4%) Storage: 953.87 GiB (1.6% used) Procs: 414
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34

Once after waking up from sleep following appeared, but usually it doesn't:
[ 133.371715] mt7921e 0000:2c:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[ 134.571894] mt7921e 0000:2c:00.0: driver own failed
[ 134.571917] mt7921e 0000:2c:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_resume+0x0/0x110 returns -5
[ 134.571938] mt7921e 0000:2c:00.0: PM: failed to resume async: error -5

Output of sudo journalctl  -b 0:
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: Linux version 6.8.0-39-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-112) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu)>
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-39-generic root=UUID=c210d5ee-f651-41d9-92b7-b187ac3430a1 ro quiet splash rdrand=force vt.handoff=7
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000038058fff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000038059000-0x0000000040731fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040732000-0x0000000040846fff] ACPI data
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040847000-0x00000000409b4fff] ACPI NVS
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000409b5000-0x00000000417fefff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000417ff000-0x00000000417fffff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000041800000-0x0000000047ffffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000048c00000-0x000000004f7fffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008b07fffff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: APIC: Static calls initialized
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: e820: update [mem 0x2e230018-0x2e254a57] usable ==> usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: e820: update [mem 0x2e230018-0x2e254a57] usable ==> usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: extended physical RAM map:
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000002e230017] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000002e230018-0x000000002e254a57] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000002e254a58-0x0000000038058fff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000038059000-0x0000000040731fff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040732000-0x0000000040846fff] ACPI data
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040847000-0x00000000409b4fff] ACPI NVS
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000409b5000-0x00000000417fefff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000417ff000-0x00000000417fffff] usable
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000041800000-0x0000000047ffffff] reserved
Aug 05 19:36:54 asus-martin kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000048c00000-0x000000004f7fffff] reserved

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and kernel 6.8.0-39-generic.

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Both the kernels you mention trying are not supported on any version of Ubuntu. 5.13.5 and 6.8.8 Why were you just randomly trying different kernels and where did you get them from?

As the OP has yet to say what version of Ubuntu he is using I suggest saying to use 6.9 is unwise.

Info: Op has used mainline kernels without success
